# How to make Raphael to work with IE8 and lesser versions?

Tags: javascript, browser, raphael

I've developed java script to draw graphical shapes using Raphael. Its perfectly works with IE9 and other browsers like firefox and google chrome. But it's not working with IE8 and lesser versions of IE. Could anyone please help me to make Raphael to work with IE8 and lesser versions.

Comment: Could you post an example of the code you are having trouble with? Raphael JS is supposed to work with IE8 (and in my experience, it does).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rapheal js supports `Firefox 3.0+, Safari 3.0+, Chrome 5.0+, Opera 9.5+ and Internet Explorer 6.0+` so if its not working in IE8 then probably you might need to check your code

Comment: Its working now. I've removed a semi-colon in between move to and line to attributes while drawing path in my code.